# Exponential Averaging using Simple averaging

Tags: regression, moving-average, exponential-smoothing

Mathematically what is the expression that is close to a 10 Day Exponential moving average (span of 10 means decay factor of 0.818181) that is created using averaging over Simple moving averages. E.g. 10D Exponential average is close to weighted average of (3D,5D,7D,10D) Simple moving averages.

Context for this : I want to run a exponentially-weighted least squares regression with huber loss (mae for outliers). But this regression does not converge, so I am thinking of averaging out non-weighted least squares with different lookbacks.

Comment: Hi: I'm not sure of I understand the question but $\lambda = \frac{1}{2n + 1}$ will give you something pretty close to a $n$ length windowed moving average. This assumes that ES is $\hat{y}_t = \lambda \hat{y}_{t-1} + (1-\lambda) S_t$. See Brown's text for a nice discussion of ES.

Comment: Text is by Robert Brown: "Smoothing, Forecasting and Prediction of Discrete Time Series".

Comment: I cannot use EMA, need to approximate n day EMA using weighted averages of x[i] day SMA where  1Day<x[i]<=10D

Comment: Hi:  I don't understand your question because there is no such thing as an $n$ day EWMA. The EWMA does not use the value of $n$. It uses $\lambda$ or $\rho$ or whatever you want to define as the EWMA parameter.

Comment: n day EMA is the same as you mentioned using decay as (1/2n+1)

Comment: Hi: Okay. I think of that as the EWMA corresponding to an n day MA. I'm still not sure if I understand the problem you're having but,  if you want to approximate in  the other direction, then just flip the relation so solve for $n$ in $\lambda = \frac{1}{2n + 1}$.